# How to visualise nested functions in Django Admin documentation generator

Tags: python, django, documentation, documentation-generation

I have a django project and inside my `views.py` file I have the following (theoretical) functions where you can see that the `get_fullname()` function is nested:

```
def dataframerequest(request, pk):
  df_re = database_sql.objects.filter(projectid=pk).values()
  df_list = [k for k in df_re]
  df = pd.DataFrame(df_list)
  return df

def get_first_name():
  first_name = 'Jack'
  return first_name

def get_last_name():
  last_name = 'Smith'
  return last_name

def get_fullname():
  first_name = get_first_name()
  last_name = get_last_name()
  full_name = first_name + ' ' + last_name
  return full_name
```

Is there a way to visualise nested functions throughout `views.py` through the Django Admin documentation generator? or is there any other product that can easily visualise the link and usage of functions between.

I have resorted to using a spreadsheet to track but I wondering if there is a better way/product that can do this automatically? This is my desired output that helps tracing back where things are used.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

To visualize the flow of code. If I understand it correctly.

### Solutions

These solution I have used while profiling and while debugging the code.

1. [Silk (profiling)](https://github.com/jazzband/django-silk): This is a great library to check the flow of code and to check the sql queries. But the best thing is, it provides a graph during you request execution like below.
   [image]
2. [PDB (Python DeBugger) (debug)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html): This I frequently use to debug the code. But it can also be used to see line by line execution of the code or function by function execution of code.
   [This tutorial helped me to understand PDB quickly.](https://github.com/spiside/pdb-tutorial)

### Suggestion

I highly recommend that you should never maintain an excel for to visualize the flow of code. Even the production applications which are stable and whose code will never change. Because in future there might come a requirement to remove or change the business logic. In that case the excel become redundant. The best way to visualise the code is by first understand the architectural flow diagram then go into the details of code.